# How to post Json data on a url and on perticular key value.? like "data" key.. with vb.net?

Tags: json, vb.net

How to post Json data on a url and on particular key value? Like "data" key.. with vb.net ?

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question. A How-To question is off topic at SO, please show us what you're trying to do, and what specific problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can post the JSON data diectly to the URL like,

```
 www.example.com/page&key="jsondata"
```

replace the & to ? to do that

```
 www.example.com/page?key="jsondata"
```